# Why doesn't isotope fill the row in this simple layout?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have a simple layout-- three colored boxes that just follow one after another in the code, all designed to fill a fixed-width `div`. Why doesn't isotope bring the blue box up next to the green box? My goal is to have all the boxes fill as much of the space as possible.

[image: the layout]

The code is super straightforward:

```
<style>
.video {
    width:435px;
    height:265px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.tweet {
    width:200px;
    height:165px;
    background-color:green;
}
.post {
    width:206px;
    height:260px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#iso {
    width:970px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
</style>

<div id='iso'>
    <div class='b video'></div>
    <div class='b tweet'></div>
    <div class='b post'></div>
    <div class='b video'></div>
    <div class='b tweet'></div>
    <div class='b post'></div>
    <div class='b video'></div>
    <div class='b tweet'></div>
    <div class='b post'></div>
</div>

$(function () {
    $('#iso').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.b',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
});
```

Feel free to play with it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pnoeric/Jn3UX/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$('#iso').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.b',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```

I think this is the effect you're trying to achieve.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn3UX/5/